# Systemd and group credentials: failed at GROUP spawning

Tags: debian, systemd, group

Recently,  one of my servers running Deb 10 stopped responding to everything except SSH.  After solving an issue where the filesystem was read-only due to a botched fstab, I am now met with almost all services failing to load, which I've begun to work on one at a time.  This is mariadb's failure, which during my Googling, seems to have something to do with systemd and group creds.  I don't know where to go from here to find out why these errors are occurring.  Could someone tell me what my first step would be in solving this issue?

```
Dec    8 09:03:39 adolf systemd[473]: mariadb.service: Failed to determine group credentials: No such process 
Dec    8 09:03:39 adolf systemd[473]: mariadb.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/install: No such process 
Dec    8 09:03:39 adolf systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Dec    8 09:03:39 adolf systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Dec    8 09:03:39 adolf systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What Group or SupplementaryGroups do you have configured in the systemd unit, and do those groups exist?

Comment: How would I determine this?  Debian wiki shows how to print groups current user is a member of but I can't seem to find how to see all groups configured in systemd.

Comment: `systemctl cat mariadb.service | grep Group`

Comment: The results of that:
root@adolf:~# systemctl cat mariadb.service | grep Group
Group=mysql

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when systemd gets updated. Try rebooting your system, or re-execute systemd only with the following command:

```bsh
systemctl daemon-reexec
```